# PHP Acess $1 from preg replace to use in class function

Tags: php, function, class, replace

I¨m trying to use the information stored in $1 and $2 in a function within a class. But I can't figure out how I am supposed to do it.

```
$message = "[product=324243]Tooltip[/product]";

$original[0] = '/\[product=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/product\]/';
$replacement[0] = $tooltip->getTooltip("$1","$2");

ksort($original);
ksort($replacement);

    $message = preg_replace($original, $replacement, $message);
```

That just gives me nothing, if I replace $1 and $2 with actual values it works fine though, so clearly the issue lands with the fact that $1 and $2 isn't proper variables outside of the preg replace function.

Comment: `$1` and `$2` in `$tooltip->getTooltip("$1","$2");` need to be in single quotes, not double quotes otherwise PHP will attempt to replace them while generate `$replacement[0]`

Comment: This still gives me an empty result though, wheres if I replace $1 and $2 with ex. '324243' and 'hover me' I do get a result. This is what confuses me, it's as if the two variables are empty and I am not sure why they would be. Appriciate the help

Comment: What does the `$tooltip->getTooltip` function do?

Comment: Just runs and returns a query to get information about the product with the id stored in $1

Comment: `$1` and `$2` work only as part of a replacement pattern, not before `preg_replace` ever runs. [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) can be used however.

Comment: PD of [Replace deprecated preg\_replace /e with preg\_replace\_callback](//stackoverflow.com/q/19245205)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the functionality you need, you will need to use `preg_replace_callback` so that you can dynamically create the replacement string:

```
$message = preg_replace_callback($original, 
                                 function ($m) {
                                     return $tooltip->getTooltip($m[1], $m[2]);
                                 },
                                 $message);
```

Comment: Ahh, I tried using _callback earlier aswell, but it finally dawned upon me that I would need to start the class within the function inside the callback and not outside of it. Appriciate the help, thanks.